# Wired/Wirless Connection not available after Ubuntu 12.04 install on Win7

Tags: installation, wireless, networking, internet-connection

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a NTFS partition on my Windows 7 machine. After installation Ubuntu will not connect to a network either Wired or Wireless. Windows 7 Networks work fine.

Ubuntu recognizes Wireless networks, prompt for authorization, yet cannot connect.

ifconfig shows local loopback (lo) and ethernet (wlan0) with no errors, no dropped packets, no overruns.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `sudo lshw -C network` output please?

Answer (score 1):

First, go to Additional Drivers and install all drivers. Your Wi-Fi network works fine as far as I can tell. Try to connect to Wi-Fi network using:

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid <Networkname>
dhcpcd -d -t 10 wlan0
```

Or maybe your local network is off. Try

```
ifconfig eth0 up
```